# PrismaClientValidationError: Argument is missing - How to resolve?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, supabase

I'm encountering a PrismaClientValidationError when trying to update a record using the Prisma ORM. The error specifically states that the argument 'companies' is missing in the 'prisma.documents_counter.update()' invocation. Here's the error message I receive:

```
PrismaClientValidationError: Invalid `prisma.documents_counter.update()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    company_id: 1
  },
  data: {
    estimate_count: {
      increment: 1
    },
+   companies: {
+     create: companiesCreateWithoutEstimatesInput | companiesUncheckedCreateWithoutEstimatesInput,   
+     connectOrCreate: companiesCreateOrConnectWithoutEstimatesInput,
+     connect: companiesWhereUniqueInput
+   }
  }
}

Argument 'companies' is missing.
```

Here are some details and code snippets related to my setup:

1. I'm using Prisma version 5.0.0
2. The error occurs when I try to update a record in the 'documents_counter' table.
3. The 'documents_counter' table has a relation to the 'companies' table, defined in the Prisma schema.
4. I'm using the 'update' method provided by Prisma to modify the 'documents_counter' record.
5. The error points to the missing 'companies' argument in the update invocation.

Here's an example code snippet that illustrates the structure of my update operation:

```js
const estimate = await prisma.documents_counter.update({
  where: {
    company_id: 1, // Replace with the actual company_id
  },
  data: {
    estimate_count: {
      increment: 1,
    },
    // Missing 'companies' argument here
  },
});
```

I have reviewed the Prisma schema, and the 'companies' field is correctly defined in the 'documents_counter' model. However, when I try to include the 'companies' field in the update operation, I receive the 'Argument 'companies' is missing' error.

Here's some part of the prisma schema:

```
model estimates {
  id                     Int               @id(map: "invoices_duplicate_pkey") @default(autoincrement())
  number                 String?
  customer_id            Int
  created_at             DateTime          @db.Timestamp(6)
  last_modified_date     DateTime?         @db.Timestamp(6)
  exp_at                 DateTime          @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
  adjustment_total       Float?            @db.Real
  adjustment_description String?
  sub_total              Float             @db.Real
  discount_total         Float?            @db.Real
  tax_total              Float             @db.Real
  total                  Float             @db.Real
  tax_inclusive          Boolean           @default(true)
  warehouse_id           Int
  company_id             Int
  companies              companies         @relation(fields: [company_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  customers              customers         @relation(fields: [customer_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  warehouses             warehouses        @relation(fields: [warehouse_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  estimates_items        estimates_items[]

  @@schema("public")
}
model companies {
  id                Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  name              String
  rnc               String?
  address           String?
  city              String?
  province          String?
  cedula            String?
  username          String              @unique @default("")
  chart_of_accounts chart_of_accounts[]
  companies_users   companies_users[]
  documents_counter documents_counter?
  documents_ncfs    documents_ncfs[]
  estimates         estimates[]
  invoices          invoices[]
  payment_methods   payment_methods[]
  taxes             taxes[]
  warehouses        warehouses[]

  @@schema("public")
}
model documents_counter {
  id              Int       @id(map: "transaction_counters_pkey") @default(autoincrement())
  company_id      Int       @unique
  invoice_prefix  String?   @default("FAC")
  invoice_count   Int?      @default(0)
  estimate_prefix String?   @default("EST")
  estimate_count  Int?      @default(0)
  companies       companies @relation(fields: [company_id], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction)

  @@schema("public")
}
```